# My car's topology is messing up as soon as I attempt to move a group of vertices along the y-axis

Tags: modeling, topology

I am modelling a car and am using edit mode to position the trunk. Whenever I move my string of vertices along the y-axis, the topology gets really strange, and it looks like one of the edges (with one of its vertices selected), is not being affected by the movement of that vertex. I do not know why this is happening. I removed the only modifier (mirror) I had on the car, and tried removing doubles. It told me it "Removed 0 vertices", and the problem is still there. Please help me!

[image: This is before I move the string of vertices. These are the only vertices that I will move for what I am attempting to do right now.]

[image: This is after I move those vertices along the y-axis. Only the right side of the car has this issue.]

Comment: You car has bad topology, the side and the trunk are huge ngons (faces with more than four sides) which is known to cause trouble. If the car is to be symmetrical, consider using a mirror modifier.

Comment: @Leadmeteor, in the upper image it seems that your back face is an Ngon: try to convert that face to regular squares, it should be easy (delete just the ngon face and rebuild it using just 4 sided (4 vertex)  geometry. Or, upload the model to http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/ and then put given link in your question, to have an example.

Comment: @Duarte Farrajota Ramos he was already using mirrors, he said.

Comment: I don't know how to clean up my topology. I uploaded my .blend to that website. Can you please show me how to fix the topology without deleting and rebuilding the car? [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=2981" />](http://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/2981/)

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I fixed it. I had to delete most of the vertices in the middle of the car and then fill in the edges and faces. It was tedious, but I did not know any better way. The only question I have now is will using the loop cut/slide tool cause bad topology again? That is what I used and it messed up my topology, so I am wondering whether or not I should continue using that tool or if there is a better way of adding more vertices. Thanks for your help!